# NodeJS Mongoose connect-mongo Session Storage with Mongo

Tags: node.js, express, connect-mongo

I try to configure my connect-mongo in the way I can use session in nodejs that is persisted with mongo. I use following code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

function connect(url, callback) {
  mongoose.connect(url);

  var connection = mongoose.connection;
  connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
  connection.once('open', function() {
      console.log("Mongoose connected at: ", url);
      callback(connection);
  });
}

var express = require("express");
var body_parser = require('body-parser');
var cookie_parser = require('cookie-parser');
var hogan_express = require('hogan-express');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongo_store = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.engine('html', hogan_express);

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set("views", "views");

app.use("/libs", express.static("bower_components"));

if (!config.development) {
    app.use(express.static("min"));
}
app.use(express.static("public"));

connect("MONGODBURL",function(mongoose_connection){
    app.use(body_parser.json());
    app.use(cookie_parser());
    app.use(session({
        secret: "asd",
        store: new mongo_store({
            mongoose_connection: mongoose_connection
            // db: mongoose_connection.db
        })
    }));

})
```

I have tried everything but executing some code I have never the object session in my res refrence.

Getting: TypeError: Cannot set property 'asd' of undefined

Code:

```
app.get("/rest/test",function(req, res) {
    req.session.asd="test";
    res.send(req.session.asd)
});
```

Somone could give a hint for a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your routes ***after*** your configure your session.

```
...
app.use(session....
...
app.get("/...
```

Inside your connect's callback in your case. Probably start listening inside it only as well.

```
connect("MONGODBURL",function(mongoose_connection){
    app.use(body_parser.json());
    app.use(cookie_parser());
    app.use(session({
        secret: "asd",
        store: new mongo_store({
            mongoose_connection: mongoose_connection
            // db: mongoose_connection.db
        })
    }));
    app.get("/rest/test",function(req, res) {
        req.session.asd="test";
        res.send(req.session.asd)
    });
    app.listen(...
});
```